# Paygreen integration with Django

Tags: django

I am a little bit lost with the integration of PayGreen payment gateway. I can't search nothing in Google, someone have one link or some example. I need to make via API with Python, I don't have another language knowledge, for the JS integration I mean. If someone can help me, it would be great.

I am lost. I have done integrations of Stripe or Monei following instructions and tutorials, but I can't find nothing for PayGreen and I need this one.

Answer (score 1):

Its given on there website, you can check here for python also: https://developers.paygreen.fr/reference/post_create_payment_order

here is example of the code to create payment request which is also there on their website:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.paygreen.fr/payment/payment-orders"

payload = {
    "auto_capture": True,
    "currency": "eur",
    "merchant_initiated": False,
    "mode": "instant",
    "partial_allowed": False,
    "amount": 100
}
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer <You token here>"
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Also, for the HTML / Javascript you can find a quick start here: https://developers.paygreen.fr/docs/paygreenjs-quickstart

Comment: Hello, I now, I have readen. But I can't make. I get first the Bearer token, I make the payment_order request but there I start having problems, and I can't start the html/javascript template. Sorry for late response but I am starting to break down.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, can you tell me how can I help you other than providing documentation.

Comment: Don't worry Diviya, thank you so much for trying to help, finally I have implemented with Hosted Pages method that they have. I don't have enough knowledge to figure the reason of failure, so I go to the easiest option :D Thanks another time.